# Apparently random 503 status code response of a REST service with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, amazon-web-services

I have a REST API developed by Node.js v8.9.4 with Hapi:

```
[GET] /api/v1/idds/:idd_id/item
```

the service execute a find on a mongoDB database:

```
function findOneWithItem(id, next) {this
.findOneById(id)
.populate('itemId')
.exec(function(err, idds) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(chalk.bgRed.white(err));
    return next(boom.badImplementation());
  }
  if (!idds) {return next(boom.notFound(errors.code400.missingResource('Idd')));} return next(null, idds);});}
```

The application is deployed on a Ubuntu VM on AWS. 
When the service is called the first time after some hours the log shows a response with an http status 503. After this firs call the service works fine again. We had the same problem with the application and the VM deployed on Azure.

Which can be the reason?

Comment: What's in your application's logs?  Is there evidence of the 503 on the server?  What about the ELB logs?  There has to be an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html

> HTTP 503: Service Unavailable
> Description: Indicates that either the load balancer or the registered instances are causing the error.
>
> Cause 1: Insufficient capacity in the load balancer to handle the request.
>
> Solution 1: This should be a transient issue and should not last more than a few minutes. If it persists, go to the AWS Support Center for assistance.
>
> Cause 2: No registered instances.
>
> Solution 2: Register at least one instance in every Availability Zone that your load balancer is configured to respond in. Verify this by looking at the HealthyHostCount metrics in CloudWatch. If you can't ensure that an instance is registered in each Availability Zone, we recommend enabling cross-zone load balancing. For more information, see Configure Cross-Zone Load Balancing for Your Classic Load Balancer.
>
> Cause 3: No healthy instances.
>
> Solution 3: Ensure that you have healthy instances in every Availability Zone that your load balancer is configured to respond in. Verify this by looking at the HealthyHostCount in CloudWatch.

Comment: The same problem was present when the application was running on the same VM on Azure. I don't think it is a problem with AWS configuration